# Dynamically Created Radio Button or CheckBox does not use Color Accent

Tags: android, themes, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

Using v21 AppCompat we can set custom color themes like following:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

But I have a bunch of dynamically created checkboxes and radio buttons **which are not inflated from xml**. These dynamically created objects do not inherit the color accent that I have specified. What can I do to set these color accents properly?

Comment: Neoh did you eventually solve your problem?

Comment: No, I have to use xml to inflate their views even if they are dynamically created, like they suggested.

Comment: Even with the new AppCompat widgets? See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can't do anything about it other than creating a layout file with just one CheckBox in it and than inflate it.

As the developers site stated: *The material theme design can only be applied when loading views using a layout inflater.*

This is because the new material design backport hooks into the layout inflation process.

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

**Edit:**
In newer versions 22.1+ of AppCompat v7 widgets like CheckBox and RadioButton can be created dynamically (no longer hidden/internal API).

Currently these widgets are supported:

- AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
- AppCompatButton
- AppCompatCheckBox
- AppCompatCheckedTextView
- AppCompatEditText
- AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView
- AppCompatRadioButton
- AppCompatRatingBar
- AppCompatSpinner
- AppCompatTextView
- AppCompatSeekBar (since 23.1)
- AppCompatImageButton (since 23.1)
- AppCompatImageView (since 23.1)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and now have a material_factory_* xml file for each of my dynamically created views. Its a bit annoying but it works:

```
// checkbox = new CeckBox(context);
checkbox = (CheckBox) View.inflate(context, R.layout.material_factory_checkbox, null);
```

And the material_factory_checkbox.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do something, apply a style on the inflating view like:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save_password_label"
        android:theme="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
        />
```

with the style:

```
<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue. You need to set the Radio Button Theme , not the Style.

```
android:theme="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
```

Example

```
<RadioButton 
android:theme="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

P.s this is working on dynamically created Radio Buttons

Answer (score -1):

Try using AppCompatCheckBox from support library:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;

AppCompatCheckBox cb =  new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
```